# Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?

Tags: r, dataframe, insert

The following code combines a vector with a dataframe:

```
newrow = c(1:4)
existingDF = rbind(existingDF,newrow)
```

However this code always inserts the new row at the end of the dataframe.

How can I insert the row at a specified point within the dataframe? For example, lets say the dataframe has 20 rows, how can I insert the new row between rows 10 and 11?

Comment: Use a convenient index and sort?

Comment: `existingDF = rbind(existingDF[1:10,],newrow,existingDF[-(1:10),])`

Comment: With a simple loop and a condition if needed, rows can be appended from one dataframe into another.  A sample code is as shown below
`newdataframe[nrow(newdataframe)+1,] <- existingdataframe[i,]`

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Here's a solution that avoids the (often slow) `rbind` call:

```
existingDF <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(20),nrow=5,ncol=4))
r <- 3
newrow <- seq(4)
insertRow <- function(existingDF, newrow, r) {
  existingDF[seq(r+1,nrow(existingDF)+1),] <- existingDF[seq(r,nrow(existingDF)),]
  existingDF[r,] <- newrow
  existingDF
}

> insertRow(existingDF, newrow, r)
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  6 11 16
2  2  7 12 17
3  1  2  3  4
4  3  8 13 18
5  4  9 14 19
6  5 10 15 20
```

If speed is less important than clarity, then @Simon's solution works well:

```
existingDF <- rbind(existingDF[1:r,],newrow,existingDF[-(1:r),])
> existingDF
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1   1  6 11 16
2   2  7 12 17
3   3  8 13 18
4   1  2  3  4
41  4  9 14 19
5   5 10 15 20
```

(Note we index `r` differently).

And finally, benchmarks:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  rbind(existingDF[1:r,],newrow,existingDF[-(1:r),]),
  insertRow(existingDF,newrow,r)
)

Unit: microseconds
                                                    expr     min       lq   median       uq       max
1                       insertRow(existingDF, newrow, r) 660.131 678.3675 695.5515 725.2775   928.299
2 rbind(existingDF[1:r, ], newrow, existingDF[-(1:r), ]) 801.161 831.7730 854.6320 881.6560 10641.417
```

**Benchmarks**

As @MatthewDowle always points out to me, benchmarks need to be examined for the scaling as the size of the problem increases.  Here we go then:

```
benchmarkInsertionSolutions <- function(nrow=5,ncol=4) {
  existingDF <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(nrow*ncol),nrow=nrow,ncol=ncol))
  r <- 3 # Row to insert into
  newrow <- seq(ncol)
  m <- microbenchmark(
   rbind(existingDF[1:r,],newrow,existingDF[-(1:r),]),
   insertRow(existingDF,newrow,r),
   insertRow2(existingDF,newrow,r)
  )
  # Now return the median times
  mediansBy <- by(m$time,m$expr, FUN=median)
  res <- as.numeric(mediansBy)
  names(res) <- names(mediansBy)
  res
}
nrows <- 5*10^(0:5)
benchmarks <- sapply(nrows,benchmarkInsertionSolutions)
colnames(benchmarks) <- as.character(nrows)
ggplot( melt(benchmarks), aes(x=Var2,y=value,colour=Var1) ) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
```

@Roland's solution scales quite well, even with the call to `rbind`:

```
                                                              5       50     500    5000    50000     5e+05
insertRow2(existingDF, newrow, r)                      549861.5 579579.0  789452 2512926 46994560 414790214
insertRow(existingDF, newrow, r)                       895401.0 905318.5 1168201 2603926 39765358 392904851
rbind(existingDF[1:r, ], newrow, existingDF[-(1:r), ]) 787218.0 814979.0 1263886 5591880 63351247 829650894
```

Plotted on a linear scale:

[image: linear]

And a log-log scale:

[image: log-log]

Comment: Inserting a row at the end gives weird behaviour!

Comment: @Maarten With which function?

Comment: I guess it's the same weird behaviour I'm describing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927806/efficiently-add-numeric-columns-and-rows-with-na-and-not-knowing-colnames

Comment: The weird behaviour does not occur with insertRow2, in my particular data frame and row.

Comment: How do you just add a row of numbers to a df? I have `df` with columns `a,b,c,d` and I want to add the row `1,2,3,4`. How do I do that?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, and I realized that you can't add rows this way to TIBBLES, only to regular base R dataframes.

Answer (score 47):

```
insertRow2 <- function(existingDF, newrow, r) {
  existingDF <- rbind(existingDF,newrow)
  existingDF <- existingDF[order(c(1:(nrow(existingDF)-1),r-0.5)),]
  row.names(existingDF) <- 1:nrow(existingDF)
  return(existingDF)  
}

insertRow2(existingDF,newrow,r)

  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  6 11 16
2  2  7 12 17
3  1  2  3  4
4  3  8 13 18
5  4  9 14 19
6  5 10 15 20

microbenchmark(
+   rbind(existingDF[1:r,],newrow,existingDF[-(1:r),]),
+   insertRow(existingDF,newrow,r),
+   insertRow2(existingDF,newrow,r)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                                                    expr     min       lq   median       uq      max
1                       insertRow(existingDF, newrow, r) 513.157 525.6730 531.8715 544.4575 1409.553
2                      insertRow2(existingDF, newrow, r) 430.664 443.9010 450.0570 461.3415  499.988
3 rbind(existingDF[1:r, ], newrow, existingDF[-(1:r), ]) 606.822 625.2485 633.3710 653.1500 1489.216
```

Comment: This is a cool solution.  Still can't figure out why it's so much faster than the simultaneous call to `rbind`, but I'm intrigued.

Comment: Answers with benchmarks should have some extra reputation applied automatically IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

The `.before` argument in `dplyr::add_row` can be used to specify the row.

```
dplyr::add_row(
  cars,
  speed = 0,
  dist = 0,
  .before = 3
)
#>    speed dist
#> 1      4    2
#> 2      4   10
#> 3      0    0
#> 4      7    4
#> 5      7   22
#> 6      8   16
#> ...
```

Comment: Sometimes it is really worthwhile scrolling down a little. For me this is the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! So useful. I did not know about this dplyr function.

Comment: Just an FYI, `add_row` is imported into `dplyr` from the `tibble` package

Answer (score 10):

You should try dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
a <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
               B = c(11, 12, 13, 14))


system.time({
for (i in 50:1000) {
    b <- data.frame(A = i, B = i * i)
    a <- bind_rows(a, b)
}

})
```

Output

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.00    0.25
```

In contrast with using rbind function

```
a <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                B = c(11, 12, 13, 14))


system.time({
    for (i in 50:1000) {
        b <- data.frame(A = i, B = i * i)
        a <- rbind(a, b)
    }

})
```

Output

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.49    0.00    0.49
```

There is some performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

Insert blank row after five row in data frame and use this library package.

```
library(berryFunctions)

df <- insertRows(df, 5 , new = "")
```