# How to insert rows at variable positions in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

My original data frame shows changes on one variable (act, measured in seconds) over approx a 2-week period for several individuals (identified by Ring). My problem is that this variable stretches over the change of date (i.e. at midnight) and I wanted to split it in two: from time[i] till just at midnight, and from midnight until time[i+1]. I have added a few more variables that I need for computing these two operations:

1. modify the ith row (only when date changes) so I can get the portion of act[i] before midnight
2. insert one extra row (only when date changes) and assign it the other portion of act[i].

For example:

```
ith row: 01-01-2000 23:55:00 act= 360 seconds

i+1th row: 02-01-2000 00:01:00 act= 30 seconds

i+2th row: 02-01-2000 00:01:30 act= 50 seconds

.
.
.
```

My goal is to get:

```
ith row: 01-01-2000 23:55:00 act= 300 seconds # modified row

i+1th row: 02-01-2000 00:00:00 act= 60 seconds # inserted row

i+2th row: 02-01-2000 00:01:00 act= 30 seconds # previously row i+1th

i+3th row: 02-01-2000 00:01:30 act= 30 seconds #previously row i+2th

.
.
.
```

Data associated to each individual (Ring) stretch over a different period of time, thereby resulting in date changes between individuals that shoudn't be taken into account.
Below, a selection of my ~ 90000-row dataframe (xact) that shows date changes within and between individuals (Ring) and next my code:

```
       Ring              time  act  wd     date    clock             timepos     timemn actmn   jul
156 6106933 09/06/11 21:37:45  267 dry 09/06/11 21:37:45 2011-06-09 21:37:45 2011-06-10  8535 15134
157 6106933 09/06/11 21:42:12 3417 wet 09/06/11 21:42:12 2011-06-09 21:42:12 2011-06-10  8268 15134
158 6106933 09/06/11 22:39:09   51 dry 09/06/11 22:39:09 2011-06-09 22:39:09 2011-06-10  4851 15134
159 6106933 09/06/11 22:40:00 7317 wet 09/06/11 22:40:00 2011-06-09 22:40:00 2011-06-10  4800 15134
160 6106933 10/06/11 00:41:57   24 dry 10/06/11 00:41:57 2011-06-10 00:41:57 2011-06-11 83883 15135
529 6106933 11/06/11 22:41:57  3177 wet 11/06/11 22:41:57 2011-06-11 22:41:57 2011-06-12  4683 15136
530 6106933 11/06/11 23:34:54     6 dry 11/06/11 23:34:54 2011-06-11 23:34:54 2011-06-12  1506 15136
531 6106933 11/06/11 23:35:00  1779 wet 11/06/11 23:35:00 2011-06-11 23:35:00 2011-06-12  1500 15136
532 6106933 12/06/11 00:04:39   594 dry 12/06/11 00:04:39 2011-06-12 00:04:39 2011-06-13 86121 15137
533 6106933 12/06/11 00:14:33 18840 wet 12/06/11 00:14:33 2011-06-12 00:14:33 2011-06-13 85527 15137
7024 6134701 24/07/11 15:24:14   6 dry 24/07/11 15:24:14 2011-07-24 15:24:14 2011-07-25 30946 15179
7025 6134701 24/07/11 15:24:20   6 wet 24/07/11 15:24:20 2011-07-24 15:24:20 2011-07-25 30940 15179
7026 6134701 24/07/11 15:24:26 810 dry 24/07/11 15:24:26 2011-07-24 15:24:26 2011-07-25 30934 15179

R = unique(xact$Ring)
for ( m in R ) {
for ( i in 1:nrow(xact) ) {
if( xact$jul[i] < xact$jul[i+1] ) {
   # modify row i (jul= Julian date)
xact[i] <- c( xact$Ring[i], xact$time[i], xact$actmn[i], xact$wd[i], xact$date[i], xact$clock[i], xact$timepos[i], xact$timemn[i], xact$actmn[i], xact$jul[i] )
   # add new row between row i and row i+1
r <- i
newrow <- c( xact$Ring[i], xact$timemn[i], as.numeric(xact$timepos[i+1] - xact$timemn[i]), xact$wd[i], xact$date[i+1], xact$clock[i+1], xact$timemn[i], xact$timemn[i], xact$actmn[i], xact$jul[i+1] )
insertRow <- function( xact, newrow, r ) {
xact[seq( r+1, nrow(xact) + 1), ] <- xact[seq( r, nrow(xact) ), ]
xact[r,] <- newrow
xact
}
}
}
}
```

I tried to adapt an existing code [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe) but produces this message:

I would appreciate any help.

Santi

Comment: You don't need to insert rows. Append them and sort your data.frame. You also probably don't need loops. If you give data in a way we can read in easily (use `dput`), we could make suggestions.

Comment: @Roland you should post that as an (the best :-) ) answer.  Just create a `matrix(runif....` example so the OP understands how to `sort` or `order` his dataframe.    BTW, the clunky way to do this is `df <- rbind(df[1:j],newrowdata,df[j+1:nrow(df)])`

Comment: I've been out for a few days. Sorry for not including a dput, Carl is right. Here is zipped one with part of my dataframe:
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/419337/DF1001-zip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with made-up data:

```
#create data
DF <- data.frame(time=seq(from=strptime("2013-01-01 01:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),to=strptime("2013-01-03 01:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),by=3500))
DF$ring <- 1:2
DF <- DF[order(DF$ID),]

#apply per ring
library(plyr)
DF <- ddply(DF,.(ring),function(df){
  #index of date changes
  ind <- c(FALSE,diff(as.POSIXlt(df$time)$yday)==1)
  add <- df[ind,]
  add$time <- round(add$time,"days")
  #you can simply rbind and order, no need for inserting
  df <- rbind(df,add)
  df <- df[order(df$time),]
  #it's easier to calculate act here
  df$act <- c(diff(as.numeric(df$time)),NA)
  df})

                  time ring  act
1  2013-01-01 01:00:00    1 7000
2  2013-01-01 02:56:40    1 7000
3  2013-01-01 04:53:20    1 7000
4  2013-01-01 06:50:00    1 7000
5  2013-01-01 08:46:40    1 7000
6  2013-01-01 10:43:20    1 7000
7  2013-01-01 12:40:00    1 7000
8  2013-01-01 14:36:40    1 7000
9  2013-01-01 16:33:20    1 7000
10 2013-01-01 18:30:00    1 7000
11 2013-01-01 20:26:40    1 7000
12 2013-01-01 22:23:20    1 5800
13 2013-01-02 00:00:00    1 1200
14 2013-01-02 00:20:00    1 7000
15 2013-01-02 02:16:40    1 7000
16 2013-01-02 04:13:20    1 7000
17 2013-01-02 06:10:00    1 7000
18 2013-01-02 08:06:40    1 7000
19 2013-01-02 10:03:20    1 7000
20 2013-01-02 12:00:00    1 7000
21 2013-01-02 13:56:40    1 7000
22 2013-01-02 15:53:20    1 7000
23 2013-01-02 17:50:00    1 7000
24 2013-01-02 19:46:40    1 7000
25 2013-01-02 21:43:20    1 7000
26 2013-01-02 23:40:00    1   NA
27 2013-01-01 01:58:20    2 7000
28 2013-01-01 03:55:00    2 7000
29 2013-01-01 05:51:40    2 7000
30 2013-01-01 07:48:20    2 7000
31 2013-01-01 09:45:00    2 7000
32 2013-01-01 11:41:40    2 7000
33 2013-01-01 13:38:20    2 7000
34 2013-01-01 15:35:00    2 7000
35 2013-01-01 17:31:40    2 7000
36 2013-01-01 19:28:20    2 7000
37 2013-01-01 21:25:00    2 7000
38 2013-01-01 23:21:40    2 2300
39 2013-01-02 00:00:00    2 4700
40 2013-01-02 01:18:20    2 7000
41 2013-01-02 03:15:00    2 7000
42 2013-01-02 05:11:40    2 7000
43 2013-01-02 07:08:20    2 7000
44 2013-01-02 09:05:00    2 7000
45 2013-01-02 11:01:40    2 7000
46 2013-01-02 12:58:20    2 7000
47 2013-01-02 14:55:00    2 7000
48 2013-01-02 16:51:40    2 7000
49 2013-01-02 18:48:20    2 7000
50 2013-01-02 20:45:00    2 7000
51 2013-01-02 22:41:40    2 4700
52 2013-01-03 00:00:00    2 2300
53 2013-01-03 00:38:20    2   NA
```