# insert row in data frame without creating new columns with R

Tags: r, insert, row

I have this :

```
    1  2  3
1  10 11 12
2  13 14 15
3  16 17 18
4  19 20 21
5  22 23 24
```

And I want this :

```
    1     2  3
1  10    11 12 
2  13    14 15
3   0  0.00  
4  16    17 18
5  19    20 21
6  22    23 24
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that ?
I tried rbind, rbind.fill, smartbind, but the result is not what I expect for.

Thank you

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe

Comment: Why do you keep your data in a matrix or data.frame? If row lengths can differ a simple list of (row) vectors would be more appropriate.

Comment: I finally found a way to get what is wanted, I used rbind., but instead of having 0.000, I have 0 (0.000 is needed).. And I decided to not display NAs, but commas still stay.I have something like that : 0, 0, 0, , , , , , ,. Those problems can be solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new row is shorter than the rest. Accordingly, you would have to fill in an NA value in the third column:

```
rbind(mydf[1:2,],c(0,0,NA),mydf[3:nrow(mydf),])
```

If you insert `c(0,0)`, thus omitting the `NA` value, R will apply the vector recycling rule. This means, that the shorter vector will be "stretched" to match the required length, recycling its elements, starting again from the first. Thus effectively a vector `c(0,0,0)` will be inserted. It is up to you to choose the desired behavior (`NA` vs `0` as required value).

ADDENDUM:

If the number of colums is variable, then you can either use the answer by @asb or use the following approach:

```
mydf <- rbind(mydf[1:2,],NA,mydf[3:nrow(mydf),])
mydf[3,1:2] <- c(0,0)
```

Comment: Sorry, I was typing my answer as you posted it. So there is duplication in method. But I tried to generalize the solution.

Comment: the problem is that number of columns can change, depending on datas I import (loop on files).. So I can't fill with NA like you suggest

Comment: @LetAurn You should mention that in the question. See my addendum about vector recycling though. The vector will be stretched, but you need to specify what values do you want of course.

Comment: @LetAurn: Umm, hate to butt in but my solution handles that already.

Comment: @LetAurn A little trick using vector recycling to accommodate variable dataframe width.

Comment: strange.. It doesn't do what I want

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
insert.under.row.number <- function (mat, rnum, what) {
  if (length(what) != ncol(mat)) what <- c(what, rep_len(NA, ncol(mat) - length(what)))
  rbind(mat[1:rnum, ], what, mat[(rnum + 1):nrow(mat), ])
}
```

This will put an NA in the third column if you give what as c(0, 0.00).

---

Actually, I am just going to link to the possible duplicate that @dickoa linked to: [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe). The only thing you need to do different from that answer is this part:

```
if (length(what) != ncol(mat)) what <- c(what, rep_len(NA, ncol(mat) - length(what)))
```

So, on this difference, I am leaving my answer up. But one should check out that answer as well.

---

Here is a sample from the input file you linked to:

```
  V1      V2       V3      V4     V5          V6   V7     V8 V9   V10
1  1 4068961 731027.9 186.849 1.5000  sondage006 24.0 26.000 NA 2.000
2  1 4068963 731027.8 185.317 0.9500  sondage006 26.0 28.000 NA 2.000
3  1 4068964 731027.8 183.785 2.1000  sondage006 28.0 30.000 NA 2.000
4  1 4068965 731027.8 182.253 1.3000  sondage006 30.0 32.000 NA 2.000
5  1 4068967 731027.8 180.721 0.5000  sondage006 32.0 34.000 NA 2.000
6  1 4068916 731018.2 181.267 0.5732 sondage006A 25.8 27.667 NA 1.867
```

and this after doing: `yy <- insert.under.row.number(xx, 3, c(0, 0.0))`

```
    V1      V2       V3      V4   V5         V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1    1 4068961 731027.9 186.849 1.50 sondage006 24 26 NA   2
2    1 4068963 731027.8 185.317 0.95 sondage006 26 28 NA   2
3    1 4068964 731027.8 183.785 2.10 sondage006 28 30 NA   2
4    0       0       NA      NA   NA       <NA> NA NA NA  NA
410  1 4068965 731027.8 182.253 1.30 sondage006 30 32 NA   2
5    1 4068967 731027.8 180.721 0.50 sondage006 32 34 NA   2
```

The row names seem to have gotten messed up.

Comment: strange.. This solution doesn't do what I want.. wait, I'm posting the result

Comment: input file : http://cl.ly/143a1n1j1N2y
output file : http://cl.ly/012d3L2F2Z2D
what I want : http://cl.ly/3M3k1a0o1h1v

Comment: I am a fool. I wrote this on the fly and never ran it on my interpreter even once. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

for example you want to add rows of variable 2 to variable 1 of a data named "edges" 
just do it like this

```
allEdges <- data.frame(c(edges$V1,edges$V2))
```