# Efficiently add numeric columns and rows with NA and not knowing colnames

Tags: r, statistics

Here is a typical data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  'ID' = c("123A","456B","789C","1011","1213")
  , 'Name' = c("Alice","Bobo","Jack","Jill","Zoro")
  , 'Quizzes' = c(13,8,14,NA,15)
  , 'Midterm' = c(13,4,16,7,12)
  , 'Final' = c(15,9,13,6,13)
)
df
    ID  Name Quizzes Midterm Final
1 123A Alice      13      13    15
2 456B  Bobo       8       4     9
3 789C  Jack      14      16    13
4 1011  Jill      NA       7     6
5 1213  Zoro      15      12    13
```

I would like to add the numeric columns (excluding `'ID'` and `'Name'`) to compute a `'Grade'` column. Then I'd like to compute the mean, median, max, min, and standard deviation for each of these numeric column. And lastly, I'd like to merge the statistics to the original data frame.

One problem is that the colnames (`ID`, `Name`, `Quizzes`, `Midterm`, `Final` in this example) are unknown. The number of columns is also unknown, it may have 2 identification columns (`ID`, `Name` in this example) or more and may have 3 grade components (`Quizzes`, `Midterm`, `Final` in this example) or more.

However, I do know that the first column always contains a unique identifier.

There may be missing data and/or NA data.

When adding by column (adding horizontally), I'd like to assume that the missing and NAs are treated as zero. When adding (or computing any other statistic) by row (adding vertically), I'd like ignore the missing and NA values (treat them as outliers).

My difficulties fall into 2 categories: 1) dealing with NA and missing values, 2) merging data frames when colnames are unknown.

```
df$Means  = rowMeans(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)])
df
    ID  Name Quizzes Midterm Final    Means
1 123A Alice      13      13    15 13.66667
2 456B  Bobo       8       4     9  7.00000
3 789C  Jack      14      16    13 14.33333
4 1011  Jill      NA       7     6       NA
5 1213  Zoro      15      12    13 13.33333
```

I know how to remove NAs:

```
df$Means  = rowMeans(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)
df
    ID  Name Quizzes Midterm Final    Means
1 123A Alice      13      13    15 13.66667
2 456B  Bobo       8       4     9  7.00000
3 789C  Jack      14      16    13 14.33333
4 1011  Jill      NA       7     6  6.50000
5 1213  Zoro      15      12    13 13.33333
```

but I'd like instead to treat them as zeros.

**First Question:** Is there a one-liner to treat NAs as zero (0) without alterning the data frame?

**Edit 1:** Let me clarify that I know how to replace NAs with 0 in the data frame, with `df[is.na(df)] <-0`, but I wish to keep the original data frame's data unchanged, keeping the NAs, while computing means with NAs treated as zero.

A bit of explanation:  `sapply(df, is.numeric)` is intended to ignore the first two columns, whose colnames I do not know.

I'd also like to merge the stats into the original dataframe, for convenience of display and export to worksheet. I got part of the way, but not very far. I tried to adapt a solution described here [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe)

```
# create a dataframe of sums
data.frame(ID="Mean",t(colMeans(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)))
    ID Quizzes Midterm Final
1 Mean    12.5    10.4  11.2

# add sums to original data frame
newRow <- data.frame(ID="Mean",t(colMeans(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)))

insertRow <- function(df, r, p) {
  # df = data frame
  # r  = new row
  # p  = position
  df[seq(p+1,nrow(df)+1),] <- df[seq(p,nrow(df)),]
  df[p,] <- r
  df
} 

insertRow(df[,-1],newRow,nrow(df)+1)

    Name Quizzes Midterm Final
1  Alice    13.0    13.0  15.0
2   Bobo     8.0     4.0   9.0
3   Jack    14.0    16.0  13.0
4   Jill      NA     7.0   6.0
5   Zoro    15.0    12.0  13.0
NA  <NA>    12.5    10.4  11.2
7   <NA>      NA      NA    NA
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1L) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

**Second Question:**  How to efficiently merge my vertical sums (and means and medians and so on) back into the original data frame? Recall that I do not know the colnames, I only know that the first column is a unique identifier. **Edit:** A solution is described below.

**Edit 2:** I avoided using rbind because I am looking for an **efficient** solution. The url [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe) states that "Here's a solution that avoids the (often slow) rbind call." I do not know why rbind might be slow, but I followed the advice in trying to implement the solution given there to my present problem.

Thanks! and please do ask for clarification if needed.

**Edit 3:**

The thread I cited above, [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe), actually had an "efficient" solution to the problem that avoids the weird behaviour described with the insertRow function above (I hasten to add that the weird behaviour is most likely a result of my misusing the function). Here is a function that works and solves my second question:

```
insertRow2 <- function(df, r, p) {
  df <- rbind(df,r)
  df <- df[order(c(1:(nrow(df)-1),p-0.5)),]
  row.names(df) <- 1:nrow(df)
  return(df)  
}

insertRow2(df[,-1],newRow,nrow(df)+1)

   Name Quizzes Midterm Final
1 Alice    13.0    13.0  15.0
2  Bobo     8.0     4.0   9.0
3  Jack    14.0    16.0  13.0
4  Jill      NA     7.0   6.0
5  Zoro    15.0    12.0  13.0
6  Mean    12.5    10.4  11.2
```

As for my first question, as no one-liner were forthcoming I created custom functions like this:

```
colMeanz <- function(df) {
    df[is.na(df)] <- 0
    return(colMeans(df))
}
```

Rather inelegant, but there you go. Thanks to Llopis for help with this.

Extra explanation for context: when computing one student's mean, it makes sense to treat NA as zero, while when computing the whole class's mean, it makes sense to treat NA with ´na.rm=TRUE´.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is no names I have done this to test it

```
names(df)<- NULL
```

**First Question:** To change de NA values of the data to 0 you can do df[is.na(df)]<-0 (There are more solutions but this may do, just search here in stackflow)

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
#    NA    NA NA NA NA
#1 123A Alice 13 13 15
#2 456B  Bobo  8  4  9
#3 789C  Jack 14 16 13
#4 1011  Jill  0  7  6
#5 1213  Zoro 15 12 13
```

**Second Question:** you can do just `cbind` to join the new data to the last column and `cbind` to join a new row at the end of the df. As an example this data is proximately the mean. I am not sure you need to take care of the time used by `rbind` function, if it is just a less than 100 rows it is quite good.

```
vector <- c(14, 7, 14, 4, 13)
df <- cbind(df, vector)
#     1     2  3  4  5 vector  #Note that the name is the name of the vector
#1 123A Alice 13 13 15     14
#2 456B  Bobo  8  4  9      7
#3 789C  Jack 14 16 13     14
#4 1011  Jill  0  7  6      4
#5 1213  Zoro 15 12 13     13
```

To change the names you can do `names(df)<-names.df` being names.df a vector of names you want to get. To do the means, medians an so, you can use an apply function but I don't know well enough to show you how...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Llopis. I should have clarified that I do not want to alter the NA values in the data.frame, but calculate the means under the assumption that NA is replaced by zero. I can construct a function for that, but I expect there is a simple one-liner for that.

Comment: I found a solution to the second question based on the original thread I was referring to, I will edit my question above to show it. But the first question remains open. I sense it's a simple question...