# How can I add a row manually to a dataframe?

Tags: r

This is probably a very simple answer, but I am not able to find a solution.

I have a dataframe:

```
 structure(list(year = structure(1:23, .Label = c("1990", "1991", 
"1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
"2008", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"), class = "factor"), val = c(8, 
3, 1, 17, 5, 9, 6, 7, 3, 15, 11, 6, 2, 11, 15, 11, 15, 1, 14, 
2, 15, 4, 6)), .Names = c("year", "val"), row.names = c(NA, -23L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to add a row manually (year=2009, val=20) right between 2008 and 2010 year.

I am doing this using [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe):

**#1**

```
r<-seq(4)
newrow<-c(2009,5)
insertRow <- function(df, newrow, r) {
  df[seq(r+1,nrow(df)+1),] <- df[seq(r,nrow(df)),]
  df[r,] <- newrow
  df
}

insertRow(df, newrow, r)
```

But I am getting this:

```
Error in seq.default(r, nrow(df)) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

**#2**

```
newrow<-c(2009,20)
rbind(df,newrow)

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: You don't need this function for your case. Just use `rbind`.

Comment: You mean, rbind(df,newrow)? Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Does it matter that in my dataframe, year is a factor and val is an int?

Comment: You asked 72 questions, and I guess you already were asked to provide a `dput`. Please do here.

Comment: I have added the data now.

Comment: Add new row like `newrow <- data.frame(year = 2009, val=5)` and class of existing data frame, `df$year` is factor,  so convert 'newrow$year` to same class factor, `newrow$year <- as.factor(newrow$year)` and now you can do row bind, `df <- rbind(df, newrow)`

Comment: Thanks. That appends the value at the end. How can I insert it between 2008 and 10. Or should I sort it (Though year is a factor)?