# How to insert a row into a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, insert

Suppose you have a `data.frame` object:

```
foo <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[1:10], 
          blah=1:10, foo=1:10, 
          row.names=letters[1:10])
```

I wish to insert a row at an arbitrary position in the data.frame. Maybe as the first row, maybe as the last one. However,

- the data types of the resulting data.frame must be identical to the data types in the original data frame
- the row names must be kept

I tried to do it with rbind, and ended up writing a lengthy function which still doesn't work properly. Isn't there an elegant way of doing it?

I include my function below, but I don't think it's good.

```
df.insert <- function(df, i, row, rowname) {
  if(is.null(df)) return(df)
  if(!is.list(row)) stop("row must be a list")
  if(!all(names(rowname) %in% colnames(df)))
    stop("df.insert error: all names of rowname must be in colnames of df")

  rnames <- rownames(df)
  nr <- nrow(df)
  if(i > nr) i <- nr

  for(n in colnames(df))
    if(!n %in% names(row)) row[[n]] <- NA

  if(nr == 0)      {
    ret <- data.frame(row)
    rownames(ret) <- rowname
  } else if(i == 0) { 
    ret <- rbind(row, df, make.row.names=FALSE)
    rownames(ret) <- c(rowname, rnames)
  } else if(i == nr) {
    ret <- rbind(df, row, make.row.names=FALSE)
    rownames(ret) <- c(rnames, rowname)
  } else { 
    ret <- rbind(df[1:i,], row, df[(i+1):nr,], make.row.names=FALSE)
    rownames(ret) <- c(rnames[1:i], rowname, rnames[(i+1):nr])
  }
  return(ret)
}
```

EDIT: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe-at-specific-row-index-not-appended) do not handle two things, which is (i) appending the row at the end of the data frame, and (ii) dealing with row names. However, they provide an otherwise elegant solution, which I am working on.

Comment: Could you provide a good reason for this? Why would a new row must be in certain row in a data?

Comment: @zx8754 the short answer is, because I want it to. The data frame is being plotted in a certain way and the plotting order matters for calculating the position of elements on the screen.

Comment: @989 that is a bloody good reference that you provided. I will retract my question, it *is* a duplicate. EDIT: ops, not entirely, it does not handle the row names as I want them to be handled.

Comment: "Want to" - good enough reason :) That said, maybe it is maybe is easier to review the plotting design, or use maybe an index column?

Comment: I would consider it to be way less elegant and consistent with the principles I set :-)

Comment: It's frustrating when I create an answer to a question and then go back to SO and find the question's been closed. Here's my solution:
http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=ghCXT95u

Comment: @AndrewBrēza no need to be frustrated, you can still post your answer in [duplicated target post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe-at-specific-row-index-not-appended), provided it is not posted by someone else already.

Comment: Good point, thanks @zx8754 !