# R: how to add rows based on the value in a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
line = c(1, 2, NA, 4 ,5, NA, 7)
group = c("1.0 Group A", "2.0 Group B", "3.0 Group C", "4.0 Group D", "5.0  Group E", "6.0 Group F", "7.0 Group G")
df <- data.frame(line, group)

view(df)
   line    group
1    1   1.0 Group A
2    2   2.0 Group B
3   NA   3.0 Group C
4    4   4.0 Group D
5    5   5.0 Group E
6   NA   6.0 Group F
7    7   7.0 Group G
```

What I want to do is to find all the NA value in the "line" column and place a row underneath that row in "group" column saying "Not Applicable". So that the new data frame should look like:

```
view(df)
    line    group
1    1   1.0 Group A
2    2   2.0 Group B
3   NA   3.0 Group C
4   NA   Not Applicable
5    4   4.0 Group D
6    5   5.0 Group E
7   NA   6.0 Group F
8   NA  Not Applicable
9    7   7.0 Group G
```

I am thinking about using an ifelse statement or using case_when from dplyr. But I don't know how to work it out. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a particular reason to do this? It's not a very `tidy` approach, since you are basically inserting values in your table that aren't actually values. If you want to do something at these particular boundaries, you could create a vector of indices; if you want to divide the groups for some visualisation you could make a group id variable.

Comment: Thank you @CalumYou ! Yes, I am working with a bigger data that actually requires R to automatically identify the NA and put a line of "Not Applicable" underneath it instead of me manually doing it. And I will try looking into vector of indices.

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856) for additional info, but your question is generalized to inserting multiple rows.  And I don't think that Dec 2015 dplyr solution respects the insert order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate data.frame, `ds_blank`, and then use a union query to stack, then order it by a temp variable called `index`.

```
library(magrittr)
na_index <- which(is.na(df$line))

ds_blank <- tibble::tibble(
  index   = na_index + .5,
  line    = rep(NA_real_          , length(na_index)),
  group   = rep("Not Applicable"  , length(na_index))
)

df <- df %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column("index") %>% 
  dplyr::union(ds_blank) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(index) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-index)
```

#### Result

```
> df
  line          group
1    1    1.0 Group A
2    2    2.0 Group B
3   NA    3.0 Group C
4   NA Not Applicable
5    4    4.0 Group D
6    5   5.0  Group E
7   NA    6.0 Group F
8   NA Not Applicable
9    7    7.0 Group G
```

I wanted to try [`tibble::add_row()`](http://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/add_row.html), but that apparently doesn't allow multiple rows to be inserted if you specify a position.

#### Secondary approach

...using @Gregor's tip to use a for loop.  Notice the `na_index` is reverse sorted now.

```
na_index <- sort(which(is.na(df$line)), decreasing = T)
for( i in na_index ) {
  df <- df %>% 
    tibble::add_row(
      line    = NA_integer_,
      group   = "Not Applicable",
      .after  = i
    )
}
```

Comment: You could still use `add_row` with a for loop.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but it seemed like it would have a lot of overhead, since you'd need to find the next NA row each loop instead of being able to start with a vector positions.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks.  I incorporated your suggestion.  I was trying things like [`purrr::map_dfr()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.4/topics/map) and failed to consider other approaches.

Comment: The going backwards is a clever solution to the row problem. `which` will be in order, so you don't need to sort you can just `rev(which(...))`. Another possible solution, since you know you are adding just one row each time, is to go forwards and use `na_index = which(is.na(df$line)); add_row_index = na_index + seq_along(na_index) - 1`. (I like yours better, just tossing out another option.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a base R method: split the data by the cumulative NA count, add in the new lines, recombine.

```
    df$group = as.character(df$group)
    split_df = split(df, cumsum(is.na(df$line)))
    split_df[-1] = lapply(split_df[-1], function(d) rbind(d[1, ], data.frame(line = NA, group = "Not applicable"), d[-1, ]))
    do.call(rbind, split_df)
    #     line          group
    # 0.1    1    1.0 Group A
    # 0.2    2    2.0 Group B
    # 1.3   NA    3.0 Group C
    # 1.1   NA Not applicable
    # 1.4    4    4.0 Group D
    # 1.5    5   5.0  Group E
    # 2.6   NA    6.0 Group F
    # 2.1   NA Not applicable
    # 2.7    7    7.0 Group G
```

Note that I converted `group` to `character` to make adding new values easy, and I put `NA`s in the `line` column - you can't just have blanks in a numeric vector, every element needs to either be a number or `NA`.

Comment: Very valid explanations of limitation.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor, I think that is a good correction. I will edit my question to make sure there is no blank. And thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

An solution could be achieved using `dplyr`.

The approach is simple. Add a column representing `row number`. Take out rows having line value as `NA`. Replace `group` with `Not Applicable` and increment `row number` column by 0.5. Bind those two data frames.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>% 
  bind_rows(., filter(., is.na(line)) %>% 
  mutate(group = "Not Applicable", rownum = rownum+.5)) %>% 
  arrange(rownum) %>%
  select(-rownum)


# line          group
# 1    1    1.0 Group A
# 2    2    2.0 Group B
# 3   NA    3.0 Group C
# 4   NA Not Applicable
# 5    4    4.0 Group D
# 6    5   5.0  Group E
# 7   NA    6.0 Group F
# 8   NA Not Applicable
# 9    7    7.0 Group G
```

Limitations mentioned by @Gregor are valid. Numeric column can have value as `NA` but not `blank`.

Comment: Thank you @MKR ! Do I have to increment row number?

Comment: @Connie Not really. But why to leave it for default ordering behavior with 2 rows having same value. Hence better to take control in your code and increment the rownum.

Comment: I see. Thank you! @MKR

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the `tidyr::uncount` function might also be what you're looking for. Just mark line==NA rows with a 2 in a new column, which we'll call `n`, and then `uncount` will duplicate each row based on the value in `n`. By mutating an `ifelse` that sets NA rows `n` == 2, we essentially only duplicate the NA rows directly below where they were, as opposed to at the bottom of the df and thereby needing to `arrange`. Finally, the `dplyr::mutate_at` just says to set `group` equal to "Not Applicable" if the `line` and the previous row's `line` (i.e. lag(line)) are both NA (which tells us to focus just on these duplicated rows). I'd like to think this method is also pretty scalable too!

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    modify_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(n = ifelse(is.na(line), 2, 1)) %>%
    uncount(n) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(group), ~ifelse(is.na(line) & is.na(lag(line)), "Not Applicable", .))
#   line          group
# 1    1    1.0 Group A
# 2    2    2.0 Group B
# 3   NA    3.0 Group C
# 4   NA Not Applicable
# 5    4    4.0 Group D
# 6    5   5.0  Group E
# 7   NA    6.0 Group F
# 8   NA Not Applicable
# 9    7    7.0 Group G
```