# R- add row to data frame after a specific sting/ pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I am trying to fill in some missing data in my data frame, which looks like:

```
ID  Value
1234    0001A
Text    Text 2
1235    0001A
1236    0001A
Text    Text 2
1237    0001A
1238    0001A
1239    0001A
Text    Text 2
1240    0001A
```

What I want is after every numeric value in `ID` I want  to insert a `Text` row, so the final result would be:

```
ID  Value
1234    0001A
Text    Text 2
1235    0001A
Text    
1236    0001A
Text    Text 2
1237    0001A
Text    
1238    0001A
Text    
1239    0001A
Text    Text 2
1240    0001A
Text
```

I had found this answer and Ive tried adapting it to my requirements but no joy. 
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307197/r-how-to-add-rows-based-on-the-value-in-a-column?noredirect=1&lq=1) adding row based on presence of NA values

**Example**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("1234", "Text", "1235", "1236", "Text", "1237", "1238", "1239", "Text", "1240"), Value = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0001A", "Text 2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note: ID column exists as a character element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a row number as a reference to `arrange` the data later.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number())
```

Filter the rows which has a number in `ID` but is not followed by a `'Text'`, change the `ID` value to `'Text'` and `Value` to empty string and bind to the original dataframe and `arrange`.

```
df %>%
  filter(grepl('\\d+', ID) & lead(ID, default = last(ID)) != 'Text') %>%
  mutate(ID = 'Text', Value = '') %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(row, desc(Value)) %>%
  select(-row)


#     ID  Value
#1  1234  0001A
#2  Text Text 2
#3  1235  0001A
#4  Text       
#5  1236  0001A
#6  Text Text 2
#7  1237  0001A
#8  Text       
#9  1238  0001A
#10 Text       
#11 1239  0001A
#12 Text Text 2
#13 1240  0001A
#14 Text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grepl` to find where you have numbers and `diff` to find places where to insert a new row. With `lapply`you go to each row an insert if needed with `rbind` an new row.

```
i <- grepl("^[0-9]+$", df$ID)
j <- c(diff(i) == 0, i[length(i)])
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) rbind(df[x,]
 , data.frame(ID="Text", Value="")[j[x]])))
#     ID  Value
#1  1234  0001A
#2  Text Text 2
#3  1235  0001A
#11 Text       
#4  1236  0001A
#5  Text Text 2
#6  1237  0001A
#12 Text       
#7  1238  0001A
#13 Text       
#8  1239  0001A
#9  Text Text 2
#10 1240  0001A
#14 Text
```