# Adding/duplicating rows to a dataframe based on the value in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add rows to a dataframe based on the value in a particular column.  The added rows will be duplicates of the rows already in the dataframe, with the number of rows to add based on the value of "cat_count" for that particular row.  Here's an small-scale example:

```
factor1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4")
group = c("Group_A", "Group_B", "Group_C", "Group_D")
cat_count = c(3,5,1,8)

df <- data.frame(factor1, group, cat_count)

view(df)
 factor1   group cat_count
1       1 Group A         3
2       2 Group B         5
3       3 Group C         1
4       4 Group D         8
```

The output should to look like is this ...

```
view(df)
 factor1   group cat_count
1       1 Group A         3
2       1 Group A         3
3       1 Group A         3
4       2 Group B         5
5       2 Group B         5
6       2 Group B         5
7       2 Group B         5
8       2 Group B         5
9       3 Group C         1
10      4 Group D         8
11      4 Group D         8
12      4 Group D         8
13      4 Group D         8
14      4 Group D         8
15      4 Group D         8
16      4 Group D         8
17      4 Group D         8
```

I've looked at this answer, [R: how to add rows based on the value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307197/r-how-to-add-rows-based-on-the-value-in-a-column).  It's not quite what I need, but I think it's heading in the right direction.

Does anyone have suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `uncount` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    uncount(cat_count, .remove = FALSE)
```

-output

```
    factor1   group cat_count
1        1 Group_A         3
2        1 Group_A         3
3        1 Group_A         3
4        2 Group_B         5
5        2 Group_B         5
6        2 Group_B         5
7        2 Group_B         5
8        2 Group_B         5
9        3 Group_C         1
10       4 Group_D         8
11       4 Group_D         8
12       4 Group_D         8
13       4 Group_D         8
14       4 Group_D         8
15       4 Group_D         8
16       4 Group_D         8
17       4 Group_D         8
```

---

If there are 0 values, we may need to change it to 1 if the intention is to keep that row

```
df %>%
   mutate(cat_count2 = replace(cat_count, cat_count == 0, 1)) %>%   
   uncount(cat_count2)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Can this work in cases where the value in "cat_count" is 0?  If not, can you suggest a fix?

Comment: @CJF For 0, value, what do you expect as output

Comment: @CJF Try the updated solution

Comment: Thanks.  I can simply removed the rows with 0 as necessary, or your solution above is spot on.