# Insert row/s of NAs on the Nth row to list of data.frames with N from list

Tags: r

After numerous hours I find myself unable to solve the following issue:

I have a list of dataframes. I want to insert (not replace) one or more rows of NAs (always at least one row) to every DF respectively. The numbers of NA to insert are stored in a separate list.

To illustrate, i have the following two lists:

```
#list of dataframes
listDF <- list(data.frame(1:10),data.frame(1:9))
#list of row-indexes
listRI<- list(1,c(3,5))
```

My task hence, is to insert a row of NA to the first row to the first dataframe of `listDF` and two rows of NA (row 3 and 5) to the second dataframe on `listDF`

From [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe-at-specific-row-index-not-appended/11562428#11562428), answer 156, i have made the following function:

```
  insertRow <- function(df, rowindex) {
  df[seq(rowindex+1,nrow(df)+1),] <- df[seq(rowindex,nrow(df)),]
  df[rowindex,] <- rep(NA,ncol(df))
  df
}
```

After this, I'm not sure how to proceed. Looking around SO and other pages, I figure that the Map-function might help me. The following works as long as it is only one row to add to each df. For instance this works fine:

```
#Example with insert of single row in both dataframes
Map(function(x,y){insertRow(x,y)},x=listDF,y=list(1,5))
```

This inserts one row of NA on the first row of the first df and a row of NA on the fifth row of the second df. However if I use:

```
 #Example with insert of single row in both dataframes
    Map(function(x,y){insertRow(x,y)},x=listDF,y=listRI)
```

the function does not work (since the second list of `listRI` is of length>1. What I miss, if I have understood it correctly, is a a for-loop that updates those lists/dfs of `listDF` where I want to insert several rows of NA. Can I get some input in how to solve my issue?

As always, please let me know if I need to be clearer. Best/John

Edit:
I edited the example code to not only include first number/numbers of row indexes.

Edit (again):
In case someone runs into this code and intend to use, I found a problem with the `insertRow` function if intending to add a new row to a dataframe. I solved this by editing the function as follows:

```
insertRow <- function(df, rowindex) {
if(rowindex<=nrow(df)){df[seq(rowindex+1,nrow(df)+1),] <- df[seq(rowindex,nrow(df)),]
  df[rowindex,] <- rep(NA,ncol(df))
  return(df)}
if(rowindex>=nrow(df)+1){df[nrow(df)+1,]<-rep(NA,ncol(df))
return(df)}
}
```

Comment: Do you `NA`s always fill in the first x number of rows?

Comment: No, it can anywhere in the df. I'm going to clarify this in my first post. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `for` loop to go over *listRI*.

```
Map(function(x,y){for(i in y) {x <- insertRow(x, i)}; x},x=listDF,y=listRI)
#[[1]]
#   X1.10
#1     NA
#2      1
#3      2
#4      3
#5      4
#6      5
#7      6
#8      7
#9      8
#10     9
#11    10
#
#[[2]]
#   X1.9
#1     1
#2     2
#3    NA
#4     3
#5    NA
#6     4
#7     5
#8     6
#9     7
#10    8
#11    9
```