# Map function to iterate over list

Tags: r

users,

In [Insert row/s of NAs on the Nth row to list of data.frames with N from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62408822/insert-row-s-of-nas-on-the-nth-row-to-list-of-data-frames-with-n-from-list) i received help concerning the use of loops and the Map-function. Following the help I received there, I'm currently trying to solve a similar problem - but I'm again stuck (after time spent searching at SO and elsewhere)

Here are some example data to illustrate my problem:

```
df_z_one <- data.frame(1:2,4:5,7:8)
df_z_two <- data.frame(10:11,13:14,16:17)
list_z <- list(df_z_one,df_z_two)
df_x_one <- data.frame(c(NA,1,NA),c(NA,2,NA),c(NA,3,NA))
df_x_two <- data.frame(c(2,NA,NA),c(3,NA,NA),c(4,NA,NA))
list_x <- list(df_x_one,df_x_two)
position <- list(c(1,3),c(2,3))
```

What i need is a function that replaces the rows of NAs in the dataframes of `list_x` with rows from `list_z` with `position` specifying row number in dfs of `list_x`. I tried with the following function:

```
Map(function(x,y,z){for(i in y){x[i,]<-z[i,]};x},x=list_x,y=position,z=list_z)
```

This function changes only the first row-number in each df of `list_x` on the n-th row (specified by `position`). I want it to change all rows specified by `position`. An alternative, since the rows in `list_z` and `list_x` are in the same order (the first row of dfs in `list_z` goes to the first row of dfs in `list_x` and so on), would be a function that replaces rows of NA in `list_x` with rows from `list_x`. Such function would make `position`unnecessary.

I must mention that the number of rows to replace will differ between dataframes.

Best wishes/John

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-liner will do:

```
Map(function(x, z, i) {x[i, ] <- z; x}, list_x, list_z, position)
#[[1]]
#  c.NA..1..NA. c.NA..2..NA. c.NA..3..NA.
#1            1            4            7
#2            1            2            3
#3            2            5            8
#
#[[2]]
#  c.2..NA..NA. c.3..NA..NA. c.4..NA..NA.
#1            2            3            4
#2           10           13           16
#3           11           14           17
```

The trick is to see how to do it with one of the lists' members, then try to generalize that code:

```
df_x_one[position[[1]],] <- df_z_one
df_x_one
```

Note that the second line above is important, it corresponds to the `x` after the semi-colon in the `Map` instruction. The data.frame `x` must be returned to caller, if not it only changes inside the anonymous function called by `Map`.