# How to add an empty row to a data frame and place it exactly between two specific existing rows?

Tags: r

So I have a data frame, df1 with 992 rows and another, df2 with 991 rows (because I had to remove one of the rows from the latter). I want to bind them together (with a cbind) but they have different row numbers, so I want to add an empty row to df1 exactly between row 94 and 95. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: why not set the row from df2 NA, instead of deleting it, in the first place?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11561856/1412059

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
newdf <- rbind(df[1:94,], NA, df[95:nrow(df),])
```

Comment: Need to reset the rownames

Answer (score 2):

```
> df <- data.frame(C1 = round(rnorm(100,10,1)),
+                  C2 = round(rnorm(100,10,1)))
> tail(df, 10)
    C1 C2
91   9 10
92  11 11
93  10 10
94   9 10
95  10 10
96  13 10
97  10  9
98   9  9
99   9 11
100 11  7
> df <- rbind(df[1:94, ], c('',''),df[95:100,])
> rownames(df) <- NULL
> tail(df, 10)
    C1 C2
92  11 11
93  10 10
94   9 10
95       
96  10 10
97  13 10
98  10  9
99   9  9
100  9 11
101 11  7
>
```