# How to add rows when time interval straddles minute mark

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with speech events timed from `start` to `end` in milliseconds:

```
df <- data.frame(
  speaker = c(NA, "A", NA, "B", NA, "C", NA, "C"),
  start = c(0,20000,35000,65000,80000,100000,110000,140000),
  end = c(20000,35000,65000,80000,100000,110000,140000,195000)
)
```

I need to **add** rows when `start` and `end` times of a row **straddle** a full-minute mark, while **clipping** the `end` time of the straddling row to the exact full-minute mark (`60000`, `120000`etc.) and **assigning** the 'rest' to the `end` value in the added row. The desired output would be:

```
  speaker  start    end
1    <NA>      0  20000
2       A  20000  35000
3    <NA>  35000  60000   # clipped end time
4    <NA>  60000  65000   # added row
5       B  65000  80000
6    <NA>  80000 100000
7       C 100000 110000
8    <NA> 110000 120000   # clipped end time
9    <NA> 120000 140000   # added row
10      C 140000 120000   # clipped end time
11      C 120000 195000   # added row
```

**EDIT**:

Here's my (long-winded) solution:

***Step 1***: Create a dataframe in which the minute-straddling row is flagged:

```
df0 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    minute_start = as.integer(start/60000),
    minute_end = as.integer(end/60000),
    straddler = minute_end > minute_start)
```

***Step 2***: Create another dataframe subsetted on the flagged rows, where the `end` value is `mutate`d to the exact minute mark:

```
df1 <- df0 %>%
  filter(straddler=="TRUE") %>%
  mutate(end = minute_end*60000)
```

***Step 3***: Create another dataframe subsetted on the flagged rows, where the `start` value is `mutate`d to the exact minute mark:

```
df2 <- df0 %>%
  filter(straddler=="TRUE") %>%
  mutate(start = minute_end*60000)
```

***Step 4***: Create another dataframe *without* the flagged rows:

```
df3 <- df0 %>%
  filter(!straddler == "TRUE")
```

***Step 5***: Finally, `rbind` the the dataframes, `arrange`ing them by `start`:

```
arrange(rbind(df1, df2, df3), start)
   speaker  start    end minute_start minute_end straddler
1     <NA>      0  20000            0          0     FALSE
2        A  20000  35000            0          0     FALSE
3     <NA>  35000  60000            0          1      TRUE
4     <NA>  60000  65000            0          1      TRUE
5        B  65000  80000            1          1     FALSE
6     <NA>  80000 100000            1          1     FALSE
7        C 100000 110000            1          1     FALSE
8     <NA> 110000 120000            1          2      TRUE
9     <NA> 120000 140000            1          2      TRUE
10       C 140000 180000            2          3      TRUE
11       C 180000 195000            2          3      TRUE
```

If anybody knows how to improve this, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Not to  over complicate, but if this were an editing schedule wouldn't you want your added line, indeed all starts coming after end (line 2 onward) to start with +1, 20001 as this is the 'rest', non-inclusive. Better than me will weigh in but I know indexing milliseconds can be bewitching, especially combined with truth tables.

Comment: And perhaps this ['dplyr::add_row, .before .after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe-at-specific-row-index-not-appended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! I came up with this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

mutate(df, across(-speaker, ~ floor(.x / 60000) + 1, .names = "mnt_{.col}")) %>%
  pmap(\(...) {
    with(list(...), if (mnt_start == mnt_end) tibble(speaker, start, end)
                    else tibble(speaker = rep(speaker, 2),
                                start = c(start, mnt_start * 60000),
                                end = c(mnt_start * 60000, end)))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Returning:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   speaker  start    end
   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 NA           0  20000
 2 A        20000  35000
 3 NA       35000  60000
 4 NA       60000  65000
 5 B        65000  80000
 6 NA       80000 100000
 7 C       100000 110000
 8 NA      110000 120000
 9 NA      120000 140000
10 C       140000 180000
11 C       180000 195000
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can't run the code. Are you sure the code you posted is complete? Is there perhaps a package that needs to be installed?

Comment: Just `dplyr`, `tibble` and `purrr` from tidyverse. I included the depencies now – sorry, I assumed you were working with tidyverse already

Comment: `Error: unexpected input in:
"mutate(df, across(-speaker, ~ floor(.x / 60000) + 1, .names = "mnt_{.col}")) %>%
  pmap(\"`The issue is with the backslash

Comment: Ah! Substitute the backslash with `function` for now and upgrade to R 4.1 later ;)

Comment: A super cool solution! If you had some time to provide a little explanation for more pedestrian users like me ...

Comment: Thanks, I'd be happy to! `pmap(df, \(...) { })` or `pmap(df, function(...))` iterates over the dataset rowwise with an anonymous function that takes all the column names as arguments. `with(list(...), { })` provides the column names to the internals, even when they are `NA` (that was tricky!). We return simply the row or a modified version based on the minute arithmetic. Finally put everything together rowwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry about this - I don't have RStudio installed (new laptop), so I can't provide a code solution right now.

But one general approach to this is:

- Take your end times, which is a list of values.
- Generate a list of full-minute mark values, using seq, starting from 60000 all the way to your max end time. seq(60000, 195000, 60000)
- Merge the 2 lists, then identify unique values, then sort the list.
- This is your list of end times. Your list of start times is straightforwardly generated by just adding 0 to the start of this list and chopping off the last value.
- Now you'll have the list of times, and need to get the appropriate speakers.
- You can use ifelse logic to reassign the speakers based on whether they're in between a certain start/end time in your original dataframe. For example, if start is between 35000 and 65000 speaker is NA.
- And you're done.

Comment: There's always the terminal.