# How to insert a row into a named vector at a specific place?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm struggling to realize this task. I have a simple, named vector with random values like:

```
heights <- c(
"Anna" = 165.3,
"Philipp" = 170.1,
"Ludwig" = 181.4,
"Carina" = 155.0,
"Lisa" = 172.5,
"Andrea" = 167.9,
"Karim" = 179.1)
```

Now, assuming I want to add a row of one value right between row 1 and row 2, hence between the labels Anna and Phillip - how do I approach this?

```
heights[1] <- c("Matthias" = 167.1) # this only edits the value but not heights[1] name
```

rbind() has been unsuccessful for me because of the one column of heights and it adding the new vector at the end of the original vector. I am also unable to edit the "Anna" name of heights[1], which removes the possibility of adding and re-arranging the vector. Any tips?

rbind() does not seem to work with vectors
named vectors keep original labels when overwritten

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new row to dataframe, at specific row-index, not appended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561856/add-new-row-to-dataframe-at-specific-row-index-not-appended)

Comment: Those potential duplicates seem to be for adding a row to a data.frame, while you are seemingly looking for adding a single item to a named vector - something like `append(heights, values=c("Matthias"=167.1), after=1)` - I can't find a great duplicate but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/insert-elements-into-a-vector-at-given-indexes ?

Comment: thelatemail, thanks, that's the answer!